# How Do You Group Related Projects in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, asp.net-core

I'm working on a small client-server .NET Core project. It's got three parts:

1. The Client (Console App)
2. The Server-side Program (ASP.NET Core Web Api project)
3. Class Libraries used by both client and server (.NET Core Class Library)

I'm new to git and Github. Locally, I've put the solution folders into another folder, but GitHub doesn't offer folders. I'm looking for some way to group these three solutions on Github. I don't want my projects ordered randomly or alphabetically. If I create another class library for another project, I might mix them up with this project.

I've tried Organizations, but it doesn't seem to be the right feature. How do I group together related solutions under one umbrella on Github?

Comment: Why not put all the projects in the same repository? It should be working...

Comment: Philippe, I need individual repos for my projects. Github doesn't have any good solutions for this simple problem.